# How can I run Javascript from a local folder?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and can't seem to load a simple Javascript file from an html file.

I have a folder on my desktop with an .html file and a .js file

**The .html file contains the following html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p> this is a very simple HTML page</p>

        <script src=“script.js”></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Inside my .js file I have the simple Javascript text:**

```
alert("Hello world:);
```

When I open my .html file in a browser I just get the text:

*"this is a very simple HTML page"*

It doesn't run the script. I can't seem to find a way to make the .html file point to the .js script even though they are in the same folder on the desktop. What am I doing wrong? Also, I've tried to put the Javascript directly inside the html code (with the ( tags) and it doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried two different browsers. Is it a folder issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Which browsers have you used? I know chrome and IE will have issues doing this. Have you tried firefox?

Comment: alert ("Hello World"); " instead of :

Comment: Is javascript enabled in your browser?  Also, as @8BitProgrammer pointed out, you have a colon instead of a closing quote in your alert call.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the Javascript console? What are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three possibilities I can see here:

1. Your script has a colon instead of double quote
2. If the (1) is just a copy/paste error - your double quotes over "script.js" are wrong type (if you have copied/pasted this code from somewhere - just type them manually)
3. JavaScript is disabled in your browser(some browsers such as Internet Explorer will not load the JavaScript unless it served from a webserver such as apache or IIS for example).
4. To test if it is a browser issue place the javascript in a `<script></script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag. If it works using the following code then it an issue with your browser.

Example:

```
<script>
    alert("hello world");
</script>

</body><!--above script should be placed before this tag -->
```

Comment: I think this is the most comprehensive answer so far. I suppose it is also possible that the script file and html file are not in the same folder. - scratch that, he mentions they are in the same folder at the start :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in your Javascript code. Change the `:` after `world` to `"`.

```
alert("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong types of quotes in your `<script>` tag. You have to use plain, ASCII double quotes, not curly quotes.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's true, although he didn't get the same error when he copied the `alert` script.

Comment: Most likely because the editor didn't replace the quotes as the string is never finished - but that's moot and off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues:

(1) There's syntax error with your javascript. It should be (note double quote to end string):

```
alert("Hello world");
```

(2) Your double quotes were off in my text editor. It should be:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```